# reshape long to wide format dropping some rows

Tags: r, reshape

I have 5 column data frame which I would like to convert some columns from long to wide format

I have tried reshap and tidyverse and can get close but lose some rows when converting. I have the following code:

```
A<- c(30,   32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35)
B<- c('x',  'y',    'y',    'y',    'z',    'z',    'z')
C<- c('g',  'g',    'g',    'g',    'g',    'g',    'g')
sp<-    c('cr', 'cr',   'cr',   'cr',   'au',   'au',   'au')
tl<-    c(29,   36, 44, 40, 48, 54, 53)
test<-data.frame(A,B,C,sp,tl)
test$A<-as.factor(test$A)
```

which gives:

```
A   B   C   sp  tl
30  x   g   cr  29
32  y   g   cr  36
32  y   g   cr  44
32  y   g   cr  40
35  z   g   au  48
35  z   g   au  54
35  z   g   au  53
```

I would like:

```
A   B   C   cr  au
30  x   g   29  
32  y   g   36  
32  y   g   44  
32  y   g   40  
35  z   g       48
35  z   g       54
35  z   g       53
```

I tried

```
   wideT<-reshape(test, idvar = c("A","B","C"), timevar = "sp", direction 
= "wide")
```

which gets close but drops some rows (probably where A is repeated...

I would like cr and au populated with NA when missing values and retain all the data as per example above. thanks

Comment: We need a sequence column.  Try with `tidyverse`  `test %>% group_by(A, B, C) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% spread(sp, tl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a sequence column grouped by 'A', 'B', 'C' and then add the column name also in the `id.var` of `reshape`

```
test$ind <- with(test, ave(seq_along(A), A, B, C, FUN = seq_along))
reshape(test, idvar = c("A","B","C", "ind"), timevar = "sp",
   direction  = "wide")[-4]
#    A B C tl.cr tl.au
#1 30 x g    29    NA
#2 32 y g    36    NA
#3 32 y g    44    NA
#4 32 y g    40    NA
#5 35 z g    NA    48
#6 35 z g    NA    54
#7 35 z g    NA    53
```

---

or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
    group_by(A, B, C) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(sp, tl) %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   A, B, C [9]
#  A     B     C        au    cr
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 30    x     g        NA    29
#2 32    y     g        NA    36
#3 32    y     g        NA    44
#4 32    y     g        NA    40
#5 35    z     g        48    NA
#6 35    z     g        54    NA
#7 35    z     g        53    NA
```